# VBA Excel SumIf returns 0

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the SumIf-function in the code below to calculate the sum in column 309 (= what to sum) for all strings ValSrc (= what to find) in Column 308 (=where to find). The code causes no runtime error but although there should be results Excel just returns 0.

```
On Error GoTo Errorhandler
ValSrc = Cells(a, 48).Value & "/DIR/" & Cells(4, a).Value
ValFnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(5, 309), Cells(105673, 309)), Range(Cells(5, 308), Cells(105673, 308)), ValSrc)
Cells(a, b) = ValFnd
```

Edit:

```
Sub Gewichte_SumIf()

Dim a As Integer, b As Integer
Dim ValSrc As Variant, ValFnd As Double

For a = 5 To 5
    For b = 49 To 300
        If Cells(a, 306) > 0 Then
            If Cells(3, b) = Cells(a, 33) Then
                On Error GoTo Errorhandler
                'ValSrc = .Cells(a, 48).Value & "/DIR/" & .Cells(4, a).Value
                With Worksheets("DS_(2)_Abfragen")
                    Val Fnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(5, 309), .Cells(105673, 309)), .Range(.Cells(5, 308), .Cells(105673, 308)), "53.541331,10.033631<53.4977094,10.1118412<52.9314509,9.2331748<monday/DIR/39454")
                    .Cells(a, b) = ValFnd
                End With
            Else
                Cells(a, b) = ""
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next b
Next a

Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
Cells(a, b) = 0
Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked the content of `ValSrc` - does it really contain the string you are searching?

Comment: According to the local window the content of ValSrc is correct but I'm not sure if it's accepted as a string in the function. @FunThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the correct worksheet, using `.Cells` and `.Range`. Something like this:

```
With Worksheets("Name-Of-Worksheet")
    ValSrc = .Cells(a, 48).Value & "/DIR/" & .Cells(4, a).Value
    ValFnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(5, 309), .Cells(105673, 309)), .Range(.Cells(5, 308), .Cells(105673, 308)), ValSrc)
    .Cells(a, b) = ValFnd
End With
```

If you do not do it, it takes the `ActiveSheet` and probably this is not what you need.

[This is the documentation of the function.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-sumif-method-excel)

---

"The code causes no runtime error but although there should be results Excel just returns 0." - It returns 0, because of the `On Error GoTo Errorhandler`. Remove this line and see the run-time error.

Comment: That's not the problem as there is just one worksheet used. But may there be a problem considering the dimensions/types? @Vityata

Comment: @Masterarbeit3 - read the documentation and check whether you are referencing correctly the cells. E.g. `Cells(5,309)` means Row 5, Column 309 and not cell `E309`.

Comment: That´s not the problem, the referencing is correct, but the problem is with the types (**runtime error 13**)

Comment: @Masterarbeit3 - how are `ValFnd` and `ValSrc`  declared?

Comment: And try writing `debug.print Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range(.Cells...` to see whether you are getting something.

Comment: ValFnd is declared as Double, ValSrc is declared as Variant.

Comment: @Masterarbeit3 - what happens with the `Debug.Print`?

Comment: **Runtime Error 13** I also tried the code with a fix value instead of ValSrc to see what happens...but the same

Comment: Do you have any suggestions what's the problem with the types (declared)?

Comment: I guess it could be trying to sum value from type `String` in the range `Range(.Cells(5, 309), .Cells(105673, 309))`, @Masterarbeit3

Comment: 'Dim a As Integer, b As Integer
Dim ValSrc As Variant, ValFnd As Double

'ValSrc = .Cells(a, 48).Value & "/DIR/" & .Cells(4, a).Value
With Worksheets("DS_(2)_Abfragen")
Val Fnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(5, 309), .Cells(105673, 309)), .Range(.Cells(5, 308), .Cells(105673, 308)), "53.541331,10.033631<53.4977094,10.1118412<52.9314509,9.2331748<monday/DIR/39454")
.Cells(a, b) = ValFnd
End With'

Comment: @Masterarbeit3 - what is this - `53.541331,10.033631<53.4977094,10.1118412<52.9314509,9.2331748<monday/DIR/39454`

Comment: It's a concrete value (As String) of ValSrc

Answer (score 1):

The parameters for `SumIf` are:

1. Search range
2. Criteria
3. Sum range

so you should use

```
ValFnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(5, 308), Cells(105673, 308)), _
                                             ValSrc, _
                                             Range(Cells(5, 309), Cells(105673, 309)))
```